# Change the filename of a downloaded file hosted on another website

Tags: php, javascript

Is it possible to create a download link for a file on another site and change the file name? Can it be done without proxying it through my server? I'd like to achieve it without any additional bandwidth cost if possible.

EDIT:
Just an idea but can it be achieved with a flash downloader of sorts?

Answer (score 0):

You could fake it using a header redirect `header("Location:http://.....");` but the download process will probably show the real URL nevertheless - will depend on the client.

There is the `Content-Location` header but according to [this blog post](http://www.subbu.org/blog/2008/10/location-vs-content-location), it is used to specify an alternative location *for the same content about to be received here*, which makes it useless as a redirection tool.

The only other way I know is indeed through proxying.

Comment: @Starlin nope, it will tell the browser to go to the specified location instead.

Comment: Hmmm... I tried both of them. I couldn't find a browser that would accept 'location', Firefox looked like it would accept 'content-location' but the download failed... Do you know of a download flash tool.... like uploadify but for downloading... I am sure that would provide such functionality

Comment: on the off chance I tried 'downloadify' and it exists... its not quite what I am looking for.... but its in the right direction

Comment: @Starlin interesting idea! Flash could indeed fetch the data from a remote location. Sadly I don't know a ready-made tool for this